# Forward all arguments of lambda to function

Tags: kotlin, lambda, arguments, simplify

I have a function that takes a lambda as an argument:

```
fun blupp(theFun: ((a: Int, b: Int, c: String, d: String) -> Unit)) {
    theFun(1, 2, "three", "four")
}
```

I implemented a function that matches the lambda's prototype:

```
fun blah(a: Int, b: Int, c: String, d: String) {
    println("a=$a, b=$b, c=$c, d=$d")
}
```

I can pass `blah` to `blupp` like this:

```
fun main() {
    blupp { a, b, c, d -> blah(a, b, c, d) }
}
```

Is it possible to pass `blah` to `blupp` without having to re-declare all the arguments? I'm looking for some construct like these:

```
blupp { blah(it) } // doesn't compile
blupp { blah }     // doesn't compile
blupp(blah)        // doesn't compile
```

N.B.: Of course I could just inline `blah` into the call, but that's not what I want, because I call `blah` from other places as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a function reference:

```
blupp(::blah)
```

More on the [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type)

Comment: Awesome, I was looking for this, but couldn't find it!